# How to deal with closed source modules when configuring a new kernel build

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, kernel-modules, proprietary-drivers

I found this command very useful:

```
make localmodconfig
```

However, having some closed source drivers/modules is a problem because this command can't find an appropriate method for including the config parameters related to my closed-source software.

My question is: for example, if I have the `fglrx` module installed, how can I configure my kernel build?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you want to automatically rebuild the binary drivers if you are building a new kernel? If so have a look at dkms

Comment: @UlrichDangel let's put this way: what options do I have with this kind of software?

Comment: I really don't understand your problem, if you want to automatically rebuild your binary driver when you install a new kernel use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support - i don't understand what you mean with `because this command can't find an appropriate way of including the config parameters, which do not exist, related to my closed-source software`

Comment: "Closed source software" is unknown to the kernel source, so there is nothing to configure kernel side. Many such drivers come with some shim that has to be configured to match the kernel, which most probably has to be installed for this.

Answer (score 0):

Closed sources drivers are not parts of the linux kernel source distribution and, as such, cannot incidentally be built using the linux kernel makefile.
They are commonly shipped separately by the manufacturer as a pack of files, including the necessary scripts to be run following provided instructions in order for the driver to be properly installed on the  system.

In the particular case of the (now deprecated) [fglrx proprietary driver](https://www.x.org/wiki/ATIProprietaryDriver/), the needed files would be .rpm packaged and provide :

> readme file or a set of documentation pages,
> DRI compatible driver module for 2D support,
> DRI compatible driver module for OpenGL support,
> kernel module (precompiled binaries plus source/lib for self building)

and misc. other utilities

Alternatively and depending on your linux distribution and how widespread the driven hardware is, the associated repository might offer some dedicated package which could install the proprietary driver resorting to dedicated package manager's instructions like, regarding the fglrx driver in the times it was not deprecated:

```
emerge media-video/ati-drivers # gentoo portage way
apt-get install fglrx-driver # debian way
```

This is by way the preferred method since this would ensure a perfect integration with already installed software, eventually suggest dependencies upgrades (dependencies) and enable the package-manager to eventually suggest driver's upgrades when available.

Some kernel CONFIG_* options might need to be adjusted in order for the proprietary driver to operate correctly. It is the case in particular when open source alternatives to the proprietary driver are compiled in-kernel, this leading to conflicting situations.
As it would happen with the fglrx driver if `CONFIG_DRM_RADEON=[y]`

All best distributions will document these requirements in details. Of course, if any change is needed at that point, the kernel will have to be rebuilt.